# Could not compile when using FreeBSD-based tcphdr on Centos

Tags: c++11, centos, styles, freebsd

I am writing a simple program that using struct `tcphdr` in `netinet/tcp.h` as follows:

```html
#define _BSD_SOURCE 
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        struct tcphdr t;
        t.th_sport = 0;
        printf("\n%d", t.th_sport);
        return 1;
}
```

Because I want this program can work on both FreeBSD and Centos, so I am using the FreeBSD-based property. I also defined `_BSD_SOURCE` in the beginning of file. But it could not be compiled using `std=c++11` when I save this source code into `*.cpp` file. There is no member named `th_sport`. However, it is compiled perfectly by `std=c99` with `*.c` file.
What's problem here? Anyone helps me to explain this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on FreeBSD 10-STABLE. I'm running `clang++ -std=c++11 1.cpp` and it compiles fine.

Comment: Hi @arrowdodger, it compiles fine on FreeBSD but not on Centos. This problem happens on Centos. I tried with Ubuntu, it works fine. I don't know whats happen @@

Comment: It appears there is an incompatibility between libstdc++ and glibc regarding `_BSD_SOURCE`. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=108663 . It appears the workaround is to not define `_BSD_SOURCE`, and instead write two versions of code using `tcphdr`, one that uses the BSD variant (i.e. `.th_sport`) and one for non-BSD (i.e. `.source`).

Comment: Hi @DanielKO, thanks for your explanation. When I read the that bug, finally, there are two solution for above issue. First, use non-BSD variant (```source, destination```, etc) of ```tcphdr```. Second, ```#undef _GNU_SOURCE``` and ```#define _BSD_SOURCE``` in the beginning of file. The second one is not highly recommended because it's just a hack.